# argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

Issue creating a stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE register(job_id int, config jsonb) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test (sample1, sample2)
  SELECT sample1, sample2
  FROM test WHERE jsonb_object_field_text(config, 'Query');
  COMMIT;
END
$$;
`
```

How do I append the WHERE condition in the above stored procedure?
SQL should be more like

```
SELECT sample1, sample2
  FROM test WHERE (test1 like 'test%');
```

Comment: `jsonb_object_field_text` is not a standard Postgres function. But it seems it returns a `text` value, so you need to compare it with something: `where jsonb_object_field_text(..) = 'foo'`

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to compose a query from strings.